# Jest/Puppeteer - afterAll for tests in multiple files

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I have a tests written in Typescript with Jest/Puppeteer and the tests are splitted into multiple files. I want to close a browser after all tests, so I made:

```
afterAll(async () => {
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
});
```

in file, that is common for the rest (all tests import that file). But when I try to do that, I get "Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed." because browser closes too fast, before all tests are done. What should be the correct version of afterAll for this case, and how to check if tests in other files are really done, before closing a browser?